# SQL Query - Recursive Refinement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to pass into a stored procedure a string of words, delimited by spaces, and what I'd like to do is to execute SELECTs on those words such that each subsequent SELECT queries the result set before it. I've been looking into how to accomplish that with recursive CTEs, but I can't figure out a proper way to set up anchors and terminators to make the recursion work properly. I know I can do this on my server-side code (C#), but I'd love to not have to make repeated calls to the DB for something I know can be done there. Below is the stored proc, minus any split-type of operations to split the string up and any hack recursion attempts I've made (i.e., all it does is return a result set for one keyword):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE searchTests

@searchQuery varchar(200)

AS

SELECT 
    TestID, [Test Name], [Specimen Type], Methodology, [Performing Lab]
FROM RolodexTestDB
WHERE
    (RolodexTestDB.inactive IS NULL OR NOT RolodexTestDB.inactive = 'Yes')
    AND (
        RolodexTestDB.[Test Name] Like '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
        or RolodexTestDB.Methodology Like '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
        or RolodexTestDB.[Synonyms] Like '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
        or RolodexTestDB.[Specimen Type] Like '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
        or RolodexTestDB.[Included Tests] Like '%' + @searchQuery + '%'
    )
)
ORDER BY [Test Name]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "each subsequent SELECT queries the result set before it".  In non TSQL terms what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you provide a sample value for @searchQuery, some sample data in RolodexTestDB, and desired results? Otherwise it is hard to interpret exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry - bad explanation on my part. Sample value for @searchQuery might be: "blood HIV white" - what I need is for the above query to be executed 3 times (or some other solution that accomplishes the same thing) - each time the query is run, the result set is filtered down (so the first time it's run, I get any record that contains the first term; I then run the query on that result set again with the second term, and so on and so on).

Hope that made sense.

Comment: No it does not make sense - at least to me.  Filter down meaning all of the terms must be present?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ideal scenario to use a full-text index, that way you can use CONTAINS()?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

If you dont have access to a full text index, you could try splitting your string into a table, then join in that table then count the duplicates (by partitioning on the primary key. Untested example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnc_Split]
    (
      @Data VARCHAR(2000) ,
      @Sep VARCHAR(5)
    )
RETURNS @Temp TABLE
    (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      Data NVARCHAR(100)
    )
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Cnt INT
        SET @Cnt = 1
        WHILE ( CHARINDEX(@Sep, @Data) > 0 ) 
            BEGIN
                INSERT  INTO @Temp
                        ( data
                        )
                        SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Data, 1, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @Data) - 1)))
                SET @Data = SUBSTRING(@Data, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @Data) + 1, LEN(@Data))
                SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
            END
        INSERT  INTO @Temp
                ( data )
                SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Data))
        RETURN
    END

GO

DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SearchString = 'blood HIV white'

--#### Build Pattern Table
DECLARE @PatternTable TABLE
    (
      ID INT NOT NULL ,
      PATTERN VARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT  INTO @PatternTable
        ( ID ,
          PATTERN
        )
        SELECT  ID ,
                CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN Data + '%'
                     ELSE '% ' + Data + '%'
                END AS Data
        FROM    fnc_Split(@SearchString, ' ');

--#### Fetch list of matching Primary keys (repeat CTEs for each column)
WITH    PrepSearch ( PrimaryKey, MatchedWords )
          AS ( SELECT   PrimaryKey ,
                        COUNT(PrimaryKey) OVER ( PARTITION BY PrimaryKey ) AS MatchedWords
               FROM     dbo.RolodexTestDB P ( NOLOCK )
                        INNER JOIN @PatternTable S ON P.Methodology LIKE S.PATTERN COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
             ),
        SearchResults ( PRO_CODE )
          AS ( SELECT   PrimaryKey
               FROM     PrepSearch
               WHERE    MatchedWords = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @PatternTable)
               GROUP BY PrimaryKey
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    SearchResults
```